# Is there a CDN for CSS frameworks like 960GS?

Tags: cdn, css-frameworks

i wonder if there is a CDN for CSS frameworks like 960GS. since i think many ppl use it.

Answer (score 4):

I've not tried cachedcommons.org yet but they have a link for 960 and sounds like what you are asking for. If you have found any other public CDNs for CSS let me know.

http://cachedcommons.org/ are using github as a CDN.